# prove $ \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | |Im(z)| < Re(z) \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

this is for basic complex analysis:

what I'm trying to do is find an r>0 such that any disk centred at z with radius r will be in the set given in the title.

Now, I have considered finding $r>0$, and I can only think of one way to do it. To consider the set $\{z|Im(z) > - Re(z) and Re(z) > 0$ i.e. the bottom half of the original set and prove that this set is open, and do similarly for the top, but would that mean that the original set is open? If not, any other approaches?

Comment: Do you have an idea what this set looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Call $A$ your set, to prove that $A$ is open we shall show that given any point $z \in A, \ \exists\ \delta > 0\ $  so that  $B(z, \delta) \subseteq A, \ $ where $B(z, \delta)$ is the "open ball" centred in z.

Be $z \in A \subseteq \mathbb{C} $, then $z = x+iy$ with $x > y$. Let's call $\epsilon = x-y $, we have that $\epsilon > 0$.

Set now $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, we'll verify that $B(z, \epsilon/3) \subseteq A$:

Be $x' + iy' = z' \in B(z, \epsilon/3)$

then $x' \geq x-\epsilon/3 $ since $\epsilon > 0$ $\qquad \qquad \qquad (1)$

$ x- \epsilon/3 > y + \epsilon/3 $ since $x-y = \epsilon > 2\epsilon/3 $ $\qquad (2)$

$y + \epsilon/3\geq y'$ since $\epsilon > 0$ $\qquad \qquad \qquad (3)$

And from these 3 inequalities we get the thesis: $x' > y'$

Answer (score 0):

The maps $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R$, $f(z)=\mathrm{Re}(z)-|\mathrm{Im}(z) |$ is continuous. Hence
 $f^{-1}(\Bbb R_+^*)$ is open, since $\Bbb R_+^*$ is open